# WebView with other View Components

Tags: android

I want to display WebView with the other view TextView in Android application. The text view will be visible like an header.

Thanks 
Deepak

Comment: Could you make your actual question clearer?

Comment: I want to add WebView component with other component like Button, TextView etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to subdivide your layout, using something like:

```
LinearLayout masterLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
WebView wv = new WebView(context);
masterLayout.addView(wv);
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
masterLayout.addView(tv);

myActivity.setContentView(masterLayout);
```